# post link using facebook sdk on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I have the demo facebook app and without any modification this is the code:

```
  SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

  NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];

  NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
  NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"a long run", @"name",
                               @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                               @"it is fun", @"description",
                               @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];
  NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
  NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                 actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                 attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                 nil];


  [_facebook dialog:@"feed"
          andParams:params
        andDelegate:self];
```

This however doesn't post a link, it fact it only posts a normal status which the user enters.

How do I post a link using the Facebook SDK on an iPhone, using the newest version of the facebook (the graph api?)

I can't find anywhere on how to post a link from an iphone app using the facebook sdk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[_facebook dialog:@"feed"
      andParams:params
    andDelegate:self];
```

The problem is that facebook updated the API on the web, but not the SDK, so while `@"feed"` is the correct name for the dialog after the API update, the old name `stream.publish` is still used in the code. Therefore to get the params to work and actually be part of the message you have to use:

```
[_facebook dialog:@"stream.publish"
      andParams:params
    andDelegate:self]
```

[Source here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues#issue/178)

Also see iPortable's answer for another mistake by facebook.

Answer (score 2):

how can this be? you create a NSArray but put it in an NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];
```

// EDIT 2: ok as mentioned it should be `NSArray* actionLinks = …`

Comment: LOL @ facebook, that's the facebook example code, not even mine. Thanks, I found the actual problem which I'll put in an answer, but you get the bounty.

Comment: Just tried your answer, and it's actually the first NSDictionary that's wrong, so keep the Array after the = and change the first word to NSArray. You couldn't have known, and still thanks for spotting that.