# FB iOs SDK -- post on wall issue

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I was able to update status using FBStreamDialog object.  The case is i want to update it with a programmatically added message.. Any way of doing that???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need "publish_stream" for posting stream or any message you want to post without user interaction.

```
NSString *message = @"test message here";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];

[_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"facebook.Stream.publish" andParams:params
                   andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Then you can handle the response in "Delegate" methods of facebook i.e.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

Hope that helps, Please mark as answer if it does.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422306/post-link-using-facebook-sdk-on-iphone      this link also helped