# How to Insert a <a> tag link in a Facebook wall

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

How can I insert a html link like the 2 posts below with the Facebook iOS SDK?

[Link to Image!](http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/9639/screenshot20120617at518.png)

In Train Conductor and "itunes.apple.com" for The Fleas post they use a bit.ly link.

I tried to use the html tag `<a href="www.mystuff.com">`Whatever<\a> but it didn't work.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"My game in iTunes", @"name",
                               @"http://www.mystuff.com", @"link",
                               @"Check out this cool game for iPhone.", @"description",
                               nil];
```

This code works but that is just a normal post.

Comment: This post may help : [post link using facebook sdk on iphone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422306/post-link-using-facebook-sdk-on-iphone

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful, although some of the things changed.
With the help of FB documentation I could do it.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/